# List index out of range in for loop while trying to concatenate strings in 2 lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program, in which the user inputs 2 lists of strings.
say l1 and l2 which are of same size, say 'n'.
now the output must be given as the concatenated list of 1st element of l1 and last element of l2, and so on.
That is i'th element of l1 and (n-1)th element of l2.

It's giving an error "Index out of range" for the 3rd for loop

```py
n=int(input())

l1=[]

for x in range(n):

    e1=input()

    l1.append(e1)

l2=[]

for x in range(n):

    e2=input()
    l2.append(e2)

for x in range(n):

    k=l1[x]+l2[n-x]

print(k)
```

result:

```py
>>> Index out of range
```

Comment: x starts from zero and n-x is n for the first iteration when x = 0. So , the n th index is not exist in l2

Comment: In the last loop, for the first iteration, `x` is 0, hence you are trying to access the n-th index in `l2`, which it does not have. Try `l2[n-x-1]`

Comment: Also I am not sure if your `print` call is correctly indented. In this indentation you are just printing a list consisting last element of `l1` and 1st element of `l2`.

Comment: ya , print must be placed in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
for x in range(n):
    k=l1[x]+l2[n-x]
```

with this:

```
k = [a+b for a,b in zip(l1, reversed(l2))]
```

---

Basically you have to avoid indexing at all cost. And poor naming practice: `l1` looks very much like `I1` or `ll`. All your code can be simplified to:

```
n = int(input())

part1 = [input() for i in range(n)]
part2 = [input() for i in range(n)]

k = [a+b for a,b in zip(part1, reversed(part2))]
```

and so on...

---

Answering your question:

```
>>> part1 = ['app', 'ban']
>>> part2 = ['ana', 'le']
>>> print ' '.join( a+b for a,b in zip(part1, reversed(part2)))
apple banana
```

Looks fine to me.

Comment: Hey, Thank you!! but this is giving k as a list, can u help me print all the values of k as strings in the same line separated by spaces

Comment: @VisH1931 sure: `print ' '.join( k )`

Comment: Sorry I dint get you. For example l1 has app and ban as elements and l2 has ana and le as elements, then the output must be a string apple banana. plz help. I think I might be annoying you asking silly questions, but I am a beginner.

Comment: the third line print ' '.join gives an invalid syntax error

Comment: @VisH1931 if you use python3, add parenthesis as in `print( ... )`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `x` in the first iteration of loop would be 0 and then `n-0` will be `n` which is not the last array index. The last iteration number is `n-1`. 
The problem is just the starting point of the array that is need to be changed.

And also you have to initiate a new `list` to have the `results` in there.

So you need to change it like this:

```py
k = []
for x in range(n):

    k.append(l1[x]+l2[n-x-1])
```

Using this the first loop would be `n-0-1` which is `n-1`

And the last loop would be `n-(n-1)-1` which is `0`. So it ranges from `0` to `n-1` and that's perfect.

Also you can have a much simpler version like below:

```
k = [l1[x]+l2[-x-1] for x in range(n)]
```

Comment: It was my pleasure

Comment: `k` is not a list in this solution

Comment: @lenik I just thought he may want it like this. Changed the answer to be as a list of sum. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: you cannot use `k[x]` in this context, all you get is an exception. should use `k.append( ... )`

Comment: also `l2[n-x-1]` can be simplified to `l2[-x-1]` =)

Answer (score 1):

I think doing n-x-1 can solve the problem as list index start from zero and ended numberOfelement -1:

```
n=int(input())
l1=[ ]
for x in range(n):
    e1=input()
    l1.append(e1)
l2=[ ]
for x in range(n):
    e2=input()
    l2.append(e2)
for x in range(n):
    k=l1[x]+l2[n-x-1]
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input())

l1=[]
l2 =[]

for x in range(n):

    e1=input()

    l1.append(e1)


for x in range(n):
    e2=input()
    l2.append(e2)

k=''
for i,j in zip(l1,reversed(l2)):
    k+=i+j

print(k)
```

input

```
5

a

b

c

d

e

e

d

c

b

a
```

output

```
aabbccddee
```

other way to do it,

```
n = int(input())
l1 = list(map(str,input().split()))
l2 = list(map(str,input().split()))

if len(l2)==n and len(l2)==n:
    res=''
    for i,j in zip(l1, reversed(l2)):
        res+=i+j
    print(res)
else:
    print('len of string not matched')
```

input
        5
        abcde
        edcba

output

```
aabbccddee
```

solution for OP example given in comment

```
l1 = ['mot','cy'] 
l2 = ['cle','or']
#method 1
#sol = ' '.join([i+j for i,j in zip(l1,reversed(l2))])
#method 2
sol =''
for i,j in zip(l1,reversed(l2)):
    sol+=i+j+' '
sol.strip()

print(sol)
```

output

```
motor cycle
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but can you help printing the concatenated strings with spaces between them, for example l1['mot','cy'] and l2['cle','or'] then output must be motor cycle with space

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem:

```
n=int(input())
l1=[]

for x in range(n):
    e1=input()
    l1.append(e1)

l2=[]
for x in range(n):
    e2=input()
    l2.append(e2)

k=[l1[x]+l2[n-x-1] for x in range(n)]

print(k)
```